# Azure Umbraco Web Site down after azure restore

Tags: azure, umbraco, azure-web-app-service, umbraco7

Error running Reader: 
SQL Statement:
SELECT id, domainName FROM umbracoDomains ORDER BY id

I performed an Azure restore of my umbraco website which is using the umbraco.sdf file in the App_Data folder. After the restore I have this error. It errors when I try to log into the Umbraco backend. The Umrbaco.sdf file is only 64KB is that normal? It seems like Azure deleted some of the tables from the .sdf file on restore? In the meantime my site is down and there's no hope in retrieving all my data in my db. Help please!

[image]

[image: Server Error]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, restoring the web app would replace your current web app data and settings with content stored in the backup. According to your description, please try to check your db file in the specific backup as you mentioned in the above snapshot via this tool [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/).

If the size of Umrbaco.sdf file seems as normal, you could try to upload the Umrbaco.sdf file to you web app manually via [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) or [FTP](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2014/08/01/microsoft-azure-web-site-connect-to-your-site-via-ftp-and-uploaddownload-files/) for a temporary processing to make your web app available.

**Note:** When you replace the Umrbaco.sdf file, you need to add a app_offline.htm file to the root of your webserver for releasing the Umrbaco.sdf file. After you replace the db file, you could remove the app_offline.htm file to make your web app online.